# Loading the form data using dhtmlxConnector

Tags: forms, grid, dhtmlx, connector

I built dhtmlxForm with several controls and one of them is dhtmlxGrid inside container.
I need to load the form data using dhtmlxConnector render_array, but don’t know the best way to do it.

```
var myForm, myGrid;
var formData = [{type: "settings", position: "label-left", inputWidth: 150, labelWidth: 90},{type: "block", name: "buttonBlock", width: 500, list: [{type: "button", name: "btn1", value: "Patrick"},{type: "newcolumn", offsetLeft: 20},{type: "button", name: "btn2", value: "Edgar"},{type: "newcolumn", offsetLeft: 20},{type: "button", name: "btn3", value: "Renee"}]},{type: "block", width: 500, list: [{type: "input", name: "name", label: "Name"},{type: "input", name: "email", label: "E-mail"},{type: "input", name: "age", label: "Age", width: 70},{type: "select", name: "sex", label: "Sex", width: 70, options:[{text: "Male", value: "m"},{text: "Female", value: "f"}]},{type: "container", name: "userList", label: "Ordered items", inputWidth: 330, inputHeight: 200},{type: "hidden", name: "grid"}]}];
// server script name will loaded in “hidden” item with form data
var inProgress = false;
function doOnLoad() {
    myForm = new dhtmlXForm("myForm", formData);
    myForm.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(name){
        if (name.match(/^btn\d$/) != null && inProgress == false) {
            updateForm(name.replace(/btn/,""));
        }
    });
    myGrid = new dhtmlXGridObject(myForm.getContainer("userList"));
    myGrid.setSkin("dhx_skyblue");
    myGrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
    // 1st load
    updateForm(1);
}
function updateForm(index) {
    //what is the best way to do it?
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems like it exactly the way you need:

```
function updateForm(index) {
    inProgress = true;
    myForm.load("xml/user"+index+".xml", function(){
        // reload grid here
        myGrid.clearAll();
        myGrid.loadXML("xml/"+myForm.getItemValue("grid"), function(){
        inProgress = false;
        });
    });
}
```